# jQuery performance issues during scrolling

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-steps

So I am using jQuery Steps and at the first step if I have table with 100+ rows where I am generating checboxes, inputs and drop downs for each row, whole page is slow and it is impossible to scroll (I have to wait 10 secs to scroll down, my RAM and CPU goes up).

Is there some script to "optimize scroller" or what should I do regarding this problem.

Part of my code looks like:

```
<script src="/js/jquerysteps/jquery.steps.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquerysteps/jquery.steps.min.js"></script>
<section>
<table id="data-table-selection" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr class="table-bcg" id="table-header">
    <th class="td-100"><?= __('Assign?') ?></th>
    <th class="td-100"><?= __('Quantity') ?></th>
    <th><?= __('Product') ?></th>
    <th><?= __('Container action') ?></th>
    <th><?= __('Removal interval') ?></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($products as $product):
    $i++
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="checkbox big">
          <input type="checkbox" id="assigned_<?= $i ?>">
          <i class="input-helper"></i>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('item_[]', ['id' => 'product_' . $i, 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control kolicina', 'value' => '1']);
      </td>
      <td><?= $product['name'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $this->Form->input('task[]', ['label' => false, 'options' => $taskAction, 'default' => '1', 'id' => 'task_' . $i, 'class' => 'form-control select']); ?></td>
      <td><?= $this->Form->input( 'changeAction[]', [
          'label' => false,
          'options' => $removalAction,
          'default' => $selected,
          'id' => 'changeAction_' . $i,
          'class' => 'form-control select'
        ]);
        ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
</section>
<section>...</section>
```

JS code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("#myTable").steps({
        headerTag: "h3",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        autoFocus: true,
        onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
          email_cc = ', ' + $('#cc_email_order').val();
          swal({
           ...
          });
        },

        labels: {
          finish: textFinish,
          next: textNext,
          previous: textPrevious,
          loading: textPleaseWait
        },

        onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
          if (currentIndex == 0) {
            var ordered_by = $('#ordered_by').val();
            var ordered_by_email = $('#ordered_by_email').val();
            var telephone = $('#telephone').val();
            var email_cc = $('#cc_email_order').val();
             ....validation...

              $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#destination_numbers_preview').empty().append($('#destination_numbers option:selected').text());
```

... append other elements ....

```
              });
              return true;
            }
            return false;
          }
          if (currentIndex > newIndex) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      });
```

If I disable jquery-steps everything is again ok. So there is no scroll event at all but somehow jquery-steps have issue whene there is table with more than 100 products.

Comment: "what should I do regarding this problem":  create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) which reproduces the problem, then we might can help.

Comment: Maybe im missing something but nothing in your posted code is regarding any scrolling behaviour. If, like im guessing, you are using any scroll event or scroller plugin, please post relevant code in question. You have posted only server side code which seems unrelevant to your issue

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to load in less rows to start with as maybe to much data on the page.  Maybe you could load more in when you get to the bottom of the page. As you are using jQuery you could try:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
       //load more rows in
    }
 });
```

perhaps you will need to also unload stuff at the top.  When the user scrolls to the top you would need a similar function to load in what you have.

Another perhaps simpler alternative would be to paginate the results and put 1-10 on one table and then 2-20 on another tab which loads a new request and so on up to 50 or however may results you have.

Comment: It could be the problem but looks like not because OP said: `if I have table with 50+ rows`. 50 rows isn't a big deal for browser to handle. And i don't see any blocking behaviour in OP's posted code